# GPS simulating on Android emulated device

Tags: android-emulator

How can I simulate GPS on an Android device in the emulator?

I read somewhere that I should use the nmea file which is in /data/misc/location/gps

I  have not the .../location/...  directory.

I tested on platforms android 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 2.1, but nada!

Comment: It's described in this question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

Just create the directories you need.