# using Android Geolocate / Location utilities

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I have been unable to test my code on an emulator as Ive come to understand you cannot use geolocate on an emulator. Thus I'm not sure if Im initializing / using the functions utilities properly.

(I want to geolocate my phone, and print via a `TextView` the closest known address to my lat/lon fix)

Heres my code:

```
Location location;
Geocoder geocoder;
TextView Address;

private OnClickListener OnClick = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick (View src){

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        if (longitude != 0 && latitude != 0){
            try {
                List<Address> list  = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                Address address = list.get(0);          
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(address);
                String addressString = sb.toString();
                Address.setText(addressString);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this :[How to emulate GPS location on the android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)