# How to send GPS data from DDMS to service running in emulator?

Tags: android, service, ddms

How do I send GPS data from DDMS to my service running in emulator?

Thank you.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

enable GPS in for your emulator and then in DDMS left bottom corner is longitude and latitude, put your values and press send.

Comment: My activity start the service, when the activity still alive, GPS data can get through. But once my activity terminated (Service still alive) GPS data unable to send through.

Answer (score 0):

```
telnet localhost 5554
geo fix lat lng
```