# Location Services Testing

Tags: android, google-maps, service, location

I am doing some tutorials and especially the MarakanaMaps google maps demo.  I just wondered that as this is running inside the AVD shoudl I see my location on a map or does that depend on wifi/gps which the emulator can't do?

This is the tutorial website: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/311.html

Comment: This is weird! Did you run it? Just check if it was able to figure out your "emulator's location"!?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) and its answer. The answer explains thoroughly as to how to deal with location in emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Start your app and then You can manually give the lat and lng by opening ddms view and goto emulator control in left side scroll down and give the lat and lng value and click send. now you can see the location in emulator.
You can see your location in emulator if you will give lat and lng of your position.It also depends on network which download the map data.