# android- How to update the location without opening the maps/navigation app

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I want to get the exact & accurate current Location. For this, I used the location manager `requestLocationUpdates()` method but for invoking the `onLocationChanged()` method will take so much time. So I set the timer as 20sec for that. I mean `onLocationChanged()` method is not invoked even after 20sec then I decided to took the last known location. Here I am facing the problem. `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null.

But I want the location. Here I found the one solution for this. It is because of testing device don't have recent location update with the gps provider. So we need to manually open the Maps/Navigation app then it will return the location. what should we need to do for getting the location instead of opening the Maps app. I think we should do same as Maps app do for location update. How do we implement like that without opening it.

**// Get the Current Location using requestLocationUpdates**

```
public void getLocation() {

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(strProvider, 0, 0,
            CurrentlocationListener);

}

LocationListener CurrentlocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null) {

            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            String strCurrentLatitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            String strCurrentLongitude = String.valueOf(lng);

            System.out
                        .println("Current Latitude and Longitude(onLocation Changed): "
                                + strCurrentLatitude
                                + ","
                                + strCurrentLongitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};
```

**//Get the current location using the lastknownlocation.**

```
   String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(location_context);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    strProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
    Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(strProvider);
                System.out.println("location(geoPoint1): " + location);

                String strCurrentLatitude = "0", strCurrentLongitude = "0";

                if (location != null) {
                    strCurrentLatitude = String.valueOf(location
                            .getLatitude());
                    strCurrentLongitude = String.valueOf(location
                            .getLongitude());
                }
```

Comment: The obvious way -is to save the  coordinates before closing the app and load them after launch. Look here for one more solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885871/emulate-a-broadcast-in-android

Comment: @trololo: I want the current location even first time app open in this case we don't have the coordinates right. Here how should we get the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are doing in `OnLocationChanged()` is correct. Now replace code of LocationManager with this. It'll work.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);



            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);

        }
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: How do we call  onLocationChanged(location)? In My i am getting the this error The method onLocationChanged(Location) is undefined for the type RB_UpcomingExits

Comment: I think, It'll give you lat lon values continuously, you won't get null thereafter. If it is. You might need to mark it as an answer. Thanks.