# How to enable GPS in Eclipse Emulator for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

I'm struggling with activating the GPS functionality in the Android Emulator (Eclipse)

I wrote a test program for getting the current location. It's working on my Android Phone.. so I'm sure the app is working.

If I'm testing the program in the Android Emulator from Eclipse... nothing is happening! What am I missing?

I already added GPS support in the AVD
I know the Emulator control... but nothing is happening in the app.

Do I need to install some extra futures in the SDK?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 5):

With the emulator running, do a

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

to connect to the emulator. Then you can do several commands, for example:

```
geo fix (longitude) (latitude)
```

That command instructs the emulator to behave as if the phone was at those location (basically fake the GPS coordinates).

You can use google maps feature called "drop latlong marker" to get GPS coordinates for a particular place.

Comment: you mean in this format?!

geo fix 42.438878 -71.119277
geo fix 42.439227 -71.119689
geo fix 42.438917 -71.116146

Comment: I gave the coordinates...eg.
geo fix 122.084095 37.422006
geo fix 42.438878 -71.119277
geo fix 42.439227 -71.119689
geo fix 42.438917 -71.116146

after that I start the app...after a minut or so...de emulator is crashing. did I gave the geo fix in the correct format?!

Comment: I found this... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015#makechanges

It looks like the crash is a bug in the emulator...I'm running SDK r19. with emulator 2.3. I wrote this is a problem in the emulator...only workarround isusing another version of the emulator...am I right?!

Does anybody have an other soluiton for the problem?

Comment: You can use an actual phone if you have it (though you need to enable "allow fake locations" or something like that in the phone's settings). Or simply use a different emulator, it takes a couple of minutes at most to set up.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to send latitude and longitude via **Emulator Control** under **DDMS**, no need to other things.
pretty simple:)

Answer (score 0):

the geo-fix solution works , but the eclipse ui solution should also work. you are not supposed to install anything special.

try to create a new emulator (which has gps support enabled in its features) and run it , select it in the emulators list under "devices" , and then go to the emulator control . set there the location and press "Send" .

in any case , if that doesn't work , you can even install third party apps on the emulator that do the same thing :

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=location+spoofer&c=apps

Comment: thanks....I created a new emulator...higher version lower version...all the same result (crash emulator). How can I download the apk-file... It only goes by google-play...

Comment: well if you root your phone you can get the file yourself . anyway, i still have no clue why you are having problems . have you also tried to re-install eclipse and the adt&sdk? i even have the preview version 20 : http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview , not that any of the older versions had any gps problems... maybe try checking the settings of the emulator (inside the emulator  window itself, during runtime) ?

Comment: I can re-install Eclipse... will try that.
I created a new simple project with http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/ also here I have exactly the same problems. I run the app...no problems... if I send geo fix...the emulator is crashing.... today I lost a day lost with this issue :(

Comment: well i can't see any reason for this. if you really wish for something that works , you can even go as far as running it on ubuntu . if so,you can try it out by running wubi (so that you can discard of it easily when no longer needed) . the weird thing is that i think that both eclipse and android development work very well on linux.

Comment: well ubuntu is not an option...tha't completly new for me... Maybe another emulator... I already looked for it.. but I can't see how I can install my eclipse package then. Well...my phone is also no option because I need to send SMS messages to test the app....well I'm standing with my back to a wall...I guess :( If anyone is having a working emulator and SDK let me know!!

Comment: aren't there fake sms senders apps ?maybe this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=act.main  . would they work well for you for the time being, just till you figure out why the emulator doesn't work with gps faking? i think it's also possible to send sms to the device via usb , like this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d2aa672877572038 .  also , if you wish for an apk for the emulator for faking the gps , PM me and i will send it to you.

Comment: to android developer => I believe you saved my day!...for know it's a working solution! Stuppid that I didn't saw this way out! :D

Comment: what do you mean? what was the solution? does the emulator work now?

Comment: no the emulator isn't working. I changed to my real phone for now :(

Comment: did you try an emulator that has API10 instead of the latest ? maybe the newer versions have problems... anyway , if this answer helped you , please tick it.

Comment: I'm working at API10. I also tried older versions and newer versions :(

Comment: maybe try a different OS or different computer? it's just that i never had such problems .