# getlastknownlocation returns null in some devices

Tags: android, gps, lg

GetlastknownLocation returns null on LGE615 but it works well on Galaxy Pocket although both run the same version of android

```
public void setLocation() {
    LM = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
           provider = LM.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    try {
                    LM.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, this);
        if (LM != null) {
            Loc = LM.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (Loc != null) {
                //Handle location
                                              }}


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722401/gps-provider-enabled-but-getlastknownlocationprovider-returns-null) for details.
getLastKnownLocation may return null if last location is not known by the device. Probably it just take more time to initialize GPS on LGE615, than on Galaxy Pocket.