# How to capture longitude and latitude values and store them in server or text file in android app?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

i am trying to capture longitude and latitude values from android phone.i am able to display values on my external device but i cont able to display them on my emulator and showing location not found.please tell me good approach to store the values in a text file also ,please, here is my code.I created textfile in my assets folder.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

private final static String STORETEXT="storetext.txt";


LocationManager locationManager ;
String provider;
String value1;
String value2;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting LocationManager object
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        

    // Creating an empty criteria object
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);


    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider 
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);


        if(location!=null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

    // Setting Current Longitude
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    // Setting Current Latitude
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );

    value1 = tvLongitude.getText().toString();
    value2 = tvLatitude.getText().toString();

    saveClicked();




}

private void saveClicked() {



    try{
        OutputStreamWriter out=
                new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));
        out.write(value1);
        out.write(value2);
        out.close();

        Toast
    .makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();

    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+ t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();

    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the emulator, geolocation doesn't work. To test you can still [inject a geo fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

You should not use assets to store this data, you `activity.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()` or `getFilesDir()`.

Then once data is stored locally, you should focus on using a rest service to upload this data to your server and record it into a database.

Comment: thanks it helped me.and please help me to write captured image data from camera to server or file.

Comment: That is not a generic process. Do you have a server already ? Please learn how to send network request from your device, this topic is much bgger than a comment of the present answer

Comment: ok, please tell  me how to create a text file in server that accepts my longitude and latitude values to be stored when i post them using httppost method.