# Can't send location to Android emulator

Tags: android

So I have all the permissions I need in my Android project to get locations, but no matter what I do, I can't send a mock location to the device. I've tried using [`geo fix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) from the console, I've tried using the [DDMS perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966848/1291812) from Eclipse, and just about everything else.

My emulator simply refuses to get the location. And I know it isn't a bug in my code, because sometimes it will work.

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trouble trying to do this, I found that one of the following generally fixed things:

Go to the emulator, head over to Settings. Scroll down to location access, and turn off "Access to my location". Then turn it back on. Try sending the location from the DDMS perspective or `geo fix`, again.

Comment: Is it fix your problem. As i am getting the same issue as your was having.

Comment: Yes; this was the only thing that fixed this issue of the various things I tried (but perhaps one could try sacrificing a goat or some ritual dance for the Emulator Gods and report back)