# Ripple emulator GPS not overwritten

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, gps, phonegap-plugins, ripple

I am currently developing a phonegap app that makes use of the GPS API. For now I had to use the android emulator with telnet and `geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>` to simulate GPS positions. I also want to use ripple, but the problem with ripple is that the GPS signal that my app gets are my real coordinates. The coordinates on the right side of the ripples emulator do not overwrite the real ones. I am using Chrome and Linux. I have only found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665684/android-emulator-phonegap-gps-location) about this, which says:

> For debugging phonegap application outside the emulator, PhoneGap Emulation / Ripple allow you to test in desktop browser.
>
> http://emulate.phonegap.com/ "PhoneGap Emulation powered by Ripple"
>
> Click the setting gears and check "Override Geolocation".

Maybe I am total blind, but my 'Sections' section at the right panel at the emulator just allows me to turn on/off the Tooltips, the proxies and the theme. Does anyone know how I can make ripples make overwrite my real GPS coordinates. I have installed the ripple-emulator:

```
npm install -g ripple-emulator
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you figure out how to get your app to use ripple's mock GPS settings?

Comment: No, sry. I am currently using the Android emulator and send the emulator server the GPS coordinates I want it to emulate with a little Julia script. Sadly a working ripple emulator would be much better as it does not need that much performance.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I haven't yet succeeded getting it working, but I have noticed that you can install a ripple emulator extension in chrome. Did you try that? I tried it for the project I'm working on but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Hi, yes I already have tried it, but it does not work too. But the ripple extension for Chrome does not get updated, as there is now ripple for npm.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the titles of the "Settings" and "Device & Network Settings" panels to minimize them. "Geolocation" panel is 3rd down on the right.

[image: See here]

Comment: thanks, but changing the coordinates in this panel does not has any affect on the coordinates that my App gets, in a similar question they talked about a setting like `"Override Geolocation"`, this is what I do not find. Also ripple is not able to simulate the device or network settings as well, setting it to no network my app still uses my whole internet conenction