# How do I make a Telnet connection to an Android device?

Tags: android, ruby, telnet

I want to be able to make telnet calls to an Android device, for giving it a geo location similar to this answer in
"[How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279827/31252)".

I tried using the [Net::Telnet](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html) class in Ruby, and this code does seem to be doing it:

```
require 'net/telnet'     
telnet = Net::Telnet::new( "Host" => "localhost",
                           "Port" => 5554,
                           "Timeout" => 90 )
telnet.puts("geo fix -122.326 47.633")
```

I am not receiving any errors but the app doesn't get the location.

When I am running this in terminal I do not close the session, so how do I do to the same through Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

When you telnet in manually, you hit return after trying in the command,  you need to add a newline to your command.

```
telnet.puts("geo fix -122.326 47.633\n")
```

I'm not sure if there is a response to geo, but if you want to display that you can use this form:

```
telnet.cmd("geo fix -122.326 47.633\n") {|c| print c}
```