# Show current location on map using emulator that does not support gps

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, location-provider

Our android emulator has one inbuilt application "Map" which shows our approximate current location. I tried to use it to show my own location using network provider, but it still does not show my location on the emulator. Does anybody have an example which shows the current location for devices without GPS support?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gpstracker.java](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)
class in here.

Comment: I have already use GPSTracker in my most of the apps, but for non gps supported devices it does not show my location.

Comment: The class is built to support both gps and from network so it would provide from whichever is available..

Comment: when I use GPSTacker, it shows my location near to Africa, but Currently I am in India.

Comment: Its because both lat,lon is in 0, and also have u add internet,fine and coarse location permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable GPS when you test your app. It would also help if you use NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER both. So that when GPS is not available you still get the location with NETWORK_PROVIDER.

UPDATE: Also, if you are using emulator to test your app, make sure you emulate the GPS fix either from command line or using Eclipse. here is a link to stackoverflow question about how to do this [How to emulate gps location in the android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

```
Location our_location=locmngr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locmngr.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,loclis);
```

use `NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of `GPS_PROVIDER`