# Location service do not work with HAX mode in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, geolocation

I am running an application in [HAX mode](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html) and see this message

> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

So I assume my setup is correct, now the app requires a location service and I set it using [telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) and also from DDMS but the app does not get location.

If I run the emulator with out the HAX mode app finds the location though. Is there a limitation for HAX mode wrt to location services?

The message I see in logcat is this

> Location providers took too long to update, requesting last known
>   location  native_start failed in startNavigating()

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get HAX emulator working with App, I don't know what made it work but the 
RRR(restart, refresh, reboot) did the trick :| I suspect it was some stale state because when I enabled location service for google.com in browser it also hung. I did a wipe data and only then all the location services seemed to kick in.