# How to get latitude and longitude in Mono for android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

First i worked with this tutorial [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location)

to get latitude and longitude, but i get nothing, so this is my code :

```
[Activity(Label = "GetLocation", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity, ILocationListener
{
    private Location _currentLocation;
    private LocationManager _locationManager;
    private TextView _locationText;
    private TextView _addressText;
    private string _locationProvider;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _addressText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address_text);
        _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.location_text);
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.get_address_button).Click += AddressButton_OnClick;

        InitializeLocationManager();
    }

    private void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        var criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
        {
            Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
        };
        var acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            _locationProvider = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }

    private void AddressButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            _addressText.Text = "Can't determine the current location.";
            return;
        }

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var addressText = "Unable to find a location.";
            var geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            var addressList = geocoder.GetFromLocation(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 50);
            var address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();

            if (address != null)
            {
                var deviceLocation = new StringBuilder();
                for (var i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
                {
                    deviceLocation.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i))
                        .AppendLine(",");
                }
                _addressText.Text = deviceLocation.ToString();
            }
            RunOnUiThread(() => { _addressText.Text = addressText; });
        }).Start();
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _currentLocation = location;
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            _locationText.Text = "Unable to determine your location.";
        }
        else
        {
            _locationText.Text = String.Format("{0},{1}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras) { }

}
```

So please if someone has any idea about what wrong with my code i will be very appreciative.

Comment: What do you mean you "get nothing"? Do you not find a location provider? Does it not yield any location results? Do you have GPS turned on/enabled? Does it go into one of your fail states (e.g., does it output "Unable to determine your location")?

Comment: Maybe you are running this in the simulator and geo-location is turned off there?

Comment: Thanks for u're replays (@Chris Sinclair & sprinter252) what i got is  "Unable to determine your location", for the GPS how can i check if it'is enabled or not ?

Comment: @Mohammadov That's probably why then. There are a few resources on [Google](http://www.google.ca/webhp#gs_rn=15&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&cp=19&gs_id=94&xhr=t&q=android+emulator+GPS&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=android+emulator+GP&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.aWM&fp=d6bb5e75688b2e61&biw=1276&bih=1018) you can check so you can simulate a GPS location. By default, the emulator I believe has GPS turned off and (mostly) non-functional (after all, it doesn't actually have a physical GPS to use)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

There is one spot in your code where you're updating the the UI `_addressText.Text` from a background thread. That could also account for why, when you click the button, you're not seeing any address updates. See below for a snippet of the one line of code:

```
if (address != null)
{
    var deviceLocation = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
    {
        deviceLocation.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i))
            .AppendLine(",");
    }

    // Here you were updating the UI thread from the background:
    RunOnUiThread(() => _addressText.Text = deviceLocation.ToString());
}
```