# Retrieving current position causes my Android app to force close

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I put this code in my onCreate method in an app targeted at API level 17:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// connect to the GPS location service
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
               "Latitude -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
               " Longitude is -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()), 
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But it always gives me force close. I have Internet,FineLocation permissions.

```
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.b/com.example.b.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.example.b.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-14 00:33:18.057: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post your logcat here. Where is it crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing line 23 of your MainActivity is this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLatitude())
```

Put in a null check after this line

```
 Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

It is possible there is no last known location from the network provider and loc is null.

Try this:

```
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     // connect to the GPS location service
     Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

     //Try to get it from the GPS_PROVIDER
     if (loc == null)
     {
       loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
     }

     if (loc != null){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLatitude())
                            +" Longitude is -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }else{
        //If it's still null there is no other way to get the last location. Display a message if you like.
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No location found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Comment: yes it`s null so what`s the solution
I also used the class GPSTracker here and give me (0) location in Android 2.2 and force close in Android 4
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve? What do you want to do if there is no last known location?

Comment: it gave me "No Location Found"

Comment: That is because there is no location on the GPS. The code is functioning correctly.

Comment: What are you testing on?

Comment: emulator and bluestacks

Comment: That's because an emulator doesn't have GPS functionality. That is a separate issue so please mark my answer as the correct answer for this question. Here is a useful post on how to test locations with an emulator http://stackoverflow.com/a/2279827/2045570

Comment: Enable mock location in emulator.