# Eclipse Android DDMS - location control manuel fields disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am trying to enter "location controls" for my device in android eclipse. The problem is that the input fields for this is disabled so I can't enter anything. 
I HAVE selected my device.

btw. i have tried to enter location controls for a physical device and a virtual device (GenyMotion), but i's the same either way.

I hope anyone have a solution for this

Comment: I think that works for emulator... not for real device

Comment: I can't get it to work for my emulator (genyMotion)

Comment: You can telnet your emulator and provide location as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Genymotion** provides a shell that enables you to script the modification of sensor states.

- *gps activate*
  Activate the GPS sensor (if not already activated)
- *gps setlatitude*
  Set latitude (and activate GPS if not allready activated)
- *gps setlongitude*
  Set longitude (and activate GPS if not allready activated)

Or you can open the **GPS widget** that comes with it :

- The GPS widget allows *real time* activation and modifications of the position,accuracy and orientation.

More info [here](http://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/is-your-android-emulator-just-too-slow)

Comment: Well, I already have the Emulator Control open.. The problem is that I can't enter anything in the "Location Control" section... these fields are disabled

Comment: I think you have to enable it on the device!

Comment: Im sorry, what do I have to enabled? And where/how?

Comment: have you selected the manual tab in your location control ? Forget the other comment, I was thinking about real devices.

Comment: what are the specifications of your AVD? Can you take snapshots and post them?you have to make sure you created an emulator with Google APIs.

Comment: Actually i can't select any of those tabs at all (manual, GPX or KML).  I don't know how to make sure it has Google APIs because im using the Genymotion emulator. The standard Android emulator is running way too slow on my computer. anyways, here are the specs for the AVD im using: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2_2oeJkE3xAMnBaV3B5bVVsVEU/edit?usp=drive_web

Comment: Any idea how to remove the location (lat/long) sent via eclipse to the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. open a command shell
2. conect to the emulator with the command: telnet
   localhost
3. to enter a fixed location execute the command: `geo fix <longitude> <latitude> [<altitude>]`