# Do i have to register my application for location services?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

Do i have to register my application to Google's console for using location services or can i still use that service  without registering while testing my application on AVD or my phone?

Comment: No you don't need to register. In Emulator you have to just manually send GPS coordinates using ddms or adb.

Comment: @RohanKandwal so only when i will start to use my Application with google maps i will need to register for their API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to register anywhere for using location services. Registration will be required if you want to include **Google Map Api** in your code. But I must mention that you will need to include permissions to use location services and also if you are using an emulator, must know how to send GPS coordinates using **DDMS** or **ADB**.

[How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279647/1979347)

Above question will show you how to send mock GPS coordinates to Emulator using DDMS or ADB.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You don't have to register to use location services.

You need a locationmanager from which you setup listeners for the GPS.

```
if (locationManager == null) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
```

...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html