# cordova geolocation need an example that work

Tags: cordova

please, any one can show me a cordova example using the geolocation plugin that work.
I have tried according to the cordova tutorial,but still not working on emulator or on S3

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi Andrew thx for reply , code : 2 , message : Network provider is not availabe , this is on emulator , on my S3 nothing happened

Comment: The location finding is enabled in the settings? Also, check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2279827/2281093), it helped me to get the Geolocation working on the Android Emulator.

Comment: I quit cordova , everything is activated but geolocation still not working
I tried with java and android studio and it was easy to made , finally a decided to learn java