# adb -s emu geo fix not works without using telnet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, gps, adb

My app works on Google Apis 17. I want to set the gps location after an emulator is being launched.

I try to this follow [how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator).

1st. get the serials number of the emulator.

```
>adb devices
emulator-5554
```

2nd run

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu geo fix 121.4961236714487 31.24010934431376
```

There are no warnings and errors. I am programming on windows7.

It not work. However when I send gps info manually in eclipse(ADT22.6), it works. My app can locate the location correctly. What did eclipse do? How to make the adb command work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you try sending it via telnet? First you have to connect to the emulator:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Then you can use the geo command to send latitude and logitude:

```
geo fix 121.4961236714487 31.24010934431376
```

Comment: I am not trying to use `telnet`. For some os(e.g. windows 7), it is not being used as default.

Comment: Use telnet.  It's no more foreign to Windows than adb is.  Even if Microsoft is no longer shipping a client, there are plenty of others to choose from.

Comment: telnet does not work for me. I get this message "KO: unkown command try 'help"

Comment: Does not work. I get the same result with @user3712476 (7.1 Emulator)

Answer (score 0):

The command requires input of longitude latitude.

adb emu geo fix 41.4961236714487 271.24010934431376
KO: invalid latitude value. Should be in [-90,+90] range

Here's the string which works for me:

adb emu geo fix -71.2230 41.9067

Prior to reversing the input I was in Antarctica.