# Android send location change to application from adb

Tags: android, location, adb, google-play-services

I have an application that uses google play services location receiver.

I would like to test some components of it, and a convenient way to do this would be to be able to simulate or force a location change event to the device I am using for testing. I've found some documentation on sending broadcasts through adb, but I can't find any documentation that specifies if it's possible to send location change events to a device through adb.

If anyone knows how to send a location change event through adb to the device so that Google Play services will recognize a location change that would be perfect.

This seams like it should be possible otherwise how could someone debug their location change code without carrying their computer around enough to trigger a location change event.

Comment: Check this out: https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/
Basically there's a possibility to use mock location providers with android, but keep in mind that the proper permission must be set within manifest, and mock locations enabled in device's developer options.

Comment: Maybe this answers can help you.

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339110/adb-s-emu-geo-fix-not-works-without-using-telnet)
and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device)