# How to emulate step counter sensor in the Android devices?

Tags: android, android-testing, autotest

I want to emulate user's walking and count their steps for auto testing.

I tried to search for the solution, but only found [simulate the location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator).

Comment: Step counter is not a real hardware function as it is the GPS. Step calculation is the result of dealing with the accelerometers, so I think there's no way to simulate them. You'll have to walk...

Comment: @joaquin As far as I know, step counter is more than accelerometers nowadays, [many manufacture](http://blog.atmel.com/2013/05/13/samsungs-galaxy-s4-is-equipped-with-atmels-sensor-hub-mcu/) update their new mobile phone with sensor hub. And from Android 4.4, there are API to get the step counter data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy since [in reality](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) this sensor returns a float number describing the number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while activated.

So that the easiest implementation will include a method which generates just a random float within some realistic constraints (between 1 and 9999 steps):

```
public float generateStepsCount(){
        float minVal = 1.0f;
        float maxVal = 9999.0f;

        Random rand = new Random();

        return rand.nextFloat() * (maxVal - minVal) + minVal;
    }
```

PS: *TYPE_STEP_COUNTER* has been there since [API 19](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html).

Comment: Interesting... I'd like to remark that this method was introduced on API 19

Comment: @ViktorMalyi thanks for your answer. I know we can mock the counter sensor's return number. But what I need is I want to change the value which was stored in the `real` sensor devices.

Comment: @liweijian just get it and then modify:

mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mStepCounter = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

Comment: @ViktorMalyi Actually what I need is to simulate the users' walking, and send some signals to the sensor hub and tell it to update the steps' count.

Comment: @lit2019 I am facing similar issue... Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: @RujootaShah Sorry, I am not working on this issue either.

Comment: Make sure to enable the android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION in API 29.

Comment: is there an actual repo or a software that already simulate? I found a repo called sensorsimulator on github but it was from 10 years ago and it has so many issues