# Google Api Key Missing

Tags: android, api, maps, key

I am trying to launch an android wearable with an emulator, but it crashes on startup and getting  the  following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

But the weird part is i did defined it in my manifest like this:

**New editted that "works"**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wearfare.wearapp.gpswear"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- Mark this app as an Android Wear app. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <!-- Permission required for ambient mode to keep the application running. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

        <!-- API key for the Android Maps API v2. The value is defined as a string resource. -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

        <!-- Reference the wearable shared library required to support ambient mode. -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2**

I am getting the following:

```
10-07 10:04:43.972    1614-1614/com.wearfare.wearapp.gpswear W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
10-07 10:04:43.993    1614-1631/com.wearfare.wearapp.gpswear I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
    10-07 10:04:43.995    1614-1631/com.wearfare.wearapp.gpswear E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
    10-07 10:04:43.995    1614-1631/com.wearfare.wearapp.gpswear E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

**EDIT** build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
        signingConfigs {
        }
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.wearfare.wearapp.gpswear"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
        provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    }
```

xxx is the api key i put in, but still getting the same error message when running the project. any suggestions what i am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

**ALMOST THERE**

Ok Guys, it looks like it does work, but it doesnt show my map, it's a grey field. I figured out i can dismiss the app when i longpress it.

So maybe it could be something else why it isnt showing my map?

Comment: I did clean and rebuild the project btw.

Comment: is this key validated in your app in the developer console?

Comment: I made a Google Maps Android API key. Entered sha-1 with my package name. Then it generated a API key for me that i am using. So i need to do something else before i can use that specific key?

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/wear#dependencies So i probably am.

Comment: please post your build.gradle as well

Comment: I added the build.gradle.

Comment: It does work somehow, but my map is a greyfield. Can an emulator load a google map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem of the grey screen is that you didn't obtain the API key correctly. Please ensure that you have obtained the key correctly. I've had this exact problem when my key was generated for release instead of debug mode.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#obtaining_an_api_key

Comment: Hmm i created a debug keystore and created the api key from that, still no luck.. I will try to run it on my actual device later today.

Comment: Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I did, anyways i got it to work when i was debugging it on my device instead of emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your manifest and found problem in it.

**Please add `</manifest>` tag at the end of the file.**

Comment: Somehow stackoverflow doesnt add it in my code, but it is there. But i am gonna update the xml file. i changed it a bit and got it to "work" but getting another "error"

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868733/android-google-map-not-showing-my-location