# Send location updates to IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, google-api-client

How can location updates be sent directly to Intent Service? The following approach does not work. OnConnected function is called but then the intent is never received in the service:

```
...
    private PendingIntent getLocationPendingIntent(boolean shouldCreate) {
        Intent broadcast = new Intent(m_context,LocationUpdateService.class);
        int flags = shouldCreate ? 0 : PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE;
        return PendingIntent.getService(m_context, 0, broadcast, flags);
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = getLocationPendingIntent(true);        
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(m_googleApiClient, locationRequest,locationPendingIntent);
}
...
```

Intent Service:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationUpdateService extends IntentService {

    public LocationUpdateService() {
        super(LocationUpdateService.class.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startID);
        Log.d("LocationUpdateService","Location received");
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("LocationUpdateService","Intent received");

    }   
}
```

Manifest file:

```
...
<service  android:name=".LocationUpdateService" />
...
```

Comment: when you are on the emulator you have to maually set geolocation see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

have you called m_googleApiClient.connect() ??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is working and tested code that successfully sets up an IntentService as the receiver for the Intent included in the PendingIntent used for location updates, based on code found [here](http://www.zionsoft.net/2014/11/google-play-services-locations-2/).

First, the `IntentService`:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;

public class LocationUpdateService extends IntentService {

    private final String TAG = "LocationUpdateService";
    Location location;

    public LocationUpdateService() {

        super("LocationUpdateService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
            Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                 Log.d("locationtesting", "accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy() + " lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " lon: " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Activity code that registers for location updates with a `PendingIntent` that is sent to the `IntentService`:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    PendingIntent mRequestLocationUpdatesPendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mRequestLocationUpdatesPendingIntent);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        // create the Intent to use WebViewActivity to handle results
        Intent mRequestLocationUpdatesIntent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdateService.class);

        // create a PendingIntent
        mRequestLocationUpdatesPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                mRequestLocationUpdatesIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // request location updates
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest,
                mRequestLocationUpdatesPendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Resulting logs:

```
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.779702 lon: -122.3931595
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.7797023 lon: -122.3931594
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.7797022 lon: -122.3931596
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.7797021 lon: -122.3931597
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.7797021 lon: -122.3931596
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.7797019 lon: -122.3931597
 D/locationtesting﹕ accuracy: 10.0 lat: 37.7797019 lon: -122.3931597
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working for me. requestLocationUpdates is called but onHandleIntent is not.

Answer (score 0):

Intent services by their nature are meant for terminal tasks, such as receive intent from calling activity or fragment, start some task on a separate thread, and finish silently, without notifying any entity of it's termination. There is also a note documentation that onStartCommand should not be overridden for Intent Services ([IntentService][1]). My guess is that your service finishes itself when you expect it to be alive and therefore, the intent is not delivered properly.

Bound services would be a more suitable option as they allow different components to attach to themselves and perform the required communication.

Comment: My idea is to process the location update in Intent service and then terminate it until next update comes -  for me it looks like totally acceptable usage of intent service, correct me if I am wrong. Also not sure what you mean by: "finishes itself", should't I see any logging from my service methods in this case?

Comment: I see, then yes, Intent Service would be a good fit for such purpose. In this case, you only need to override onHandleIntent and handle all the location update logic there. Try eliminating onStartCommand, put place your log statements in onHandleIntent and see if onHandleIntent is getting called at all.

Comment: No still the same, I am really confused about this problem. Any ideas where should I start debugging?

Comment: Could you please post your updated code for the following pieces: activity or fragment that starts the service, service itself, and manifest where you declare the service. A good starting point to debug services would be to open Android Device Monitor, watch your process threads (by applicationId) and see if your service actually runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly - I mean `requestLocationUpdates` and get those updates in `IntentService`.

What you can do is to have a `Service` in background which requests those updates via `requestLocationUpdates` and is running all the time you want (remember about the case when device goes asleep). Then from that `Service` when location update is there received fire it towards `IntentService` and handle there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getService() method of pendingIntent and in the service's onStartCommand() you can get the corresponding intent. getBroadcast() sends a broadcast for which you need to register a broadcast receiver to listen. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my code according to your post, however, I still can't get location updates in my Intent Service. Please see my updated code in the edited question.

Comment: Check whether onConnected() is getting called or not

Comment: It is but nothing happens after that. Any ideas how could I debug this?