# onHandleIntent not firing with location updates

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-location

I am trying to listen to location changes using the Play Services Location API.
What I'm trying to do is go for the background app approach and get the updates using a `PendingIntent`. However, the onHandleIntent() function does not get called at all.

I didn't find a single source of comprehensive documentation regarding this approach. Can you tell me is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
public class LocationCollector extends IntentService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
        , GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;

    public LocationCollector(Context context){
        super("LocationCollector");
        mContext = context;
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    public void start(){
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    public void stop(){
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        Intent locationIntent = new Intent(mContext, LocationCollector.class);
        PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 1, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, request, locationPendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("Location","Api connection suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("Location","Api connection failed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if(location != null){
            String time= intent.getStringExtra("time");
            Toast.makeText(mContext,location.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer from @CommonsWare is spot on (as always). Also, the code in the answer of this question might be of help for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141631/send-location-updates-to-intentservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you tell me is there something I'm doing wrong?

First, a `Service` is a `Context`. You do not need to — or even *want* to — pass in some `Context` to it.

Second, your constructor should never be used. Replace it with a zero-argument constructor.

Third, `start()` and `stop()` are not lifecycle methods on an `IntentService`, and so I am not quite certain what you are expecting will call them. That, coupled with the previous problem, means nothing will really happen with this service.

Saying that you want an `IntentService` to handle the locations, via an `onHandleIntent()` method, is reasonable. However, something outside of that service is going to need to do the connecting and disconnecting, or you are going to need a substantially more complex service.

Comment: Thanks, I understood my mistake. What I had to do is separate my Service methods from this class that manages the collection of data. I created a different class for my IntentService and now I am getting location updates. Thanks again!