# Stopping location updates correctly, failure-safe

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

Please consider this chunk of code:

```
public class Presence implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{
          :
          :
    boolean pref_auto_mode;
          :
          :
    private Presence(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        getAppSettings();

        gApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context, this, this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
        if (!gApiClient.isConnecting() && !gApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            gApiClient.connect();
        }
    } // of constructor

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In onConnected(), gApiClient.isConnected(): " + gApiClient.isConnected());
        createLocationRequest();
        getLocation();
        getSubLocality();

        if (pref_auto_mode)
            startLocationUpdates();
    } // of onConnected()
          :
          :
    private void getAppSettings()
    {
        // Get the user's preferences
        APP_USER_SETTINGS =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

                :        
                :        
        pref_auto_mode = APP_USER_SETTINGS.getBoolean(Contract.PREF_AUTO_MODE, false);
                :        
    } // of getAppSettings()

} // of class Presence
```

This is working as expected.

In the same `Presence` class above, I am trying to *stop* the location updates when the user switches a certain setting off, with the following method:

```
public void stopLocationUpdates()
{
    if (gApiClient.isConnected())
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(gApiClient, pendingIntent);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(gApiClient, this);

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Location tracker stopped successfully.");

        requestingLocationUpdates = false;
    }
}
```

I do see the `Toast`. There are no location updates and everything is silent as expected. But after a couple of hours of moving around with the device, all of a sudden, I start getting location updates again, as in, all the code in the `onHandleIntent()` of the `IntentService` get faithfully executed when there's a location change.

To set the Auto mode, the user *has* to launch the app, so the `Presence` class will certainly be instantiated (Singleton) and whatever is set in the app is reflected onto its `pref_auto_mode` flag, if I am not wrong. Yet, I suspect this flag.

Kindly let me know what else I need to do to bring the location updates to a ***grinding halt*** instantly and ***keep it that way*** till the user switches the setting ON? Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: An intent service gets killed after it finishes doing its task so if you have any location manager in it, that too will get killed so you should probably move to a regular service for your location manager

Comment: Thanks @tyczj, I *do not* have any `LocationManager` in the `IntentService`. I need the `IntentService` behavior very much, and its all working fine, except the *stopping* of the location updates...

Comment: what I am saying is that if you are trying to get location updates in an intent service its not going to work. please clarify if you are trying to do this and if not why are you trying to stop it in the intent service vs where you have the location updates running

Comment: does your code look something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141631/send-location-updates-to-intentservice  also, show where in your code you request location updates....

Comment: Sorry, @tyczj, guess the information in the original question was not complete. Kindly see the updated question. To specifically answer your question, *NO*, I am not getting location updates in the `IntentService` and  *NO*, I am not stopping the updates in the `IntentService`

Comment: Are you checking the user setting before the call to `FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()`?

Comment: Yes, @DanielNugent, in the main activity's `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` listener, and in the main activity's `onResume()`.

Comment: Please allow me to be even more precise. Is the `stopLocationUpdates()` above, doing *all that it takes* to stop location updates, or is it missing somethings? Because I believe everything else is working as expected...

Comment: Show where you set/get/use the SharedPreference for this setting, and show your entire onConnected() override code where you request location updates

Comment: @DanielNugent, sorry for supplying code only on-demand. Please review the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Put a Toast inside the `if (pref_auto_mode)` case for testing, you will want to make sure it never gets in there when the setting is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who reviewed the code and provided valuable pointers.

I had to make another `boolean` field variable `stopLocationTrackerRequired` and set it in the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` override. Only if this flag is set, the `Presence` class's `stopLocationUpdates()` is invoked, and ***for sure*** turns off the location updates.

For completeness,:

> - Kindly let me know what else I need to do to bring the location updates to a grinding halt instantly and keep it that way till the user switches the setting ON?
> - Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

- the `stopLocationUpdates()` is doing everything required to achieve the functionality.
- I *really wonder*, but a little more control as shown above was lacking