# Google maps not working on android emulator ionic framework (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition)

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, android-emulator, ionic-framework

My app works fine on browser but doesn't render the google map on emulator.
This app is based on an exisiting app that already has a google map working fine on emulator (and device)
I think because navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition it's not triggering.
I edited AndroidManifest.xml with



but I still with this problem.
This is my controller:

```js
.controller('MapsCtrl', function($scope, Service, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $compile) {
    $ionicLoading.show();
    Service.getSedi().then(function(result){
        var sede = result.data[0];
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
            var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
            var map = new GMaps({
                div: '#maps',
                lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                lng: pos.coords.longitude
            });
            map.addMarker({
                lat: sede.indirizzo.lat,
                lng: sede.indirizzo.lng,
                title: sede.titolo,
                infoWindow: {
                    content: '<h3>' + sede.titolo+ '</h3><p style="color:black">' + sede.indirizzo.address +'</p>'
                }
            });
            //reverse geocoding (from coordinates get human readable address)
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var opt = {
                lat : pos.coords.latitude,
                lng : pos.coords.longitude,
                callback : function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(results[1].formatted_address + ' ' + myPosition);
                        map.addMarker({
                            position: myPosition,
                            infoWindow:{
                                content: '<h3>Estas aquí</h3><p style="color:black">' + results[1].formatted_address + '</p>'
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            GMaps.geocode(opt);
            //end reverse geocoding
            map.drawRoute({
                origin: [pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude],
                destination:[sede.indirizzo.lat,sede.indirizzo.lng],
                travelMode: 'driving',
                strokeColor: '#131540',
                strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                strokeWeight: 6
            });

            //search places
            var arrayId = [];
            map.addLayer('places', {
                location : new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude),
                radius : 600,
                types : ['cafe', 'bar', 'food'],
                search: function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            var place = results[i];
                            //here I can use place.place_id
                            arrayId.push(place.place_id);
                            map.addMarker({
                                lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                                lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
                                title : place.name,
                                infoWindow : {
                                    content : '<h3>'+place.name+'</h3><p style="color:black">'+(place.vicinity ? place.vicinity : place.formatted_address)+'</p><img src="'+place.icon+'"" height="20px"/>'
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //map.zoomOut(5);
            //Creo el div y los botones
            var node = document.createElement("div");
            var text = document.createTextNode("ACA VAN LOS BOTONES");
            node.appendChild(text);
            node.setAttribute("id", "mapBottom");
            document.getElementById("maps").appendChild(node);
        },function(error){
           $ionicPopup.alert({
               title: 'Error',
               template: 'code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n'
           });
        });
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    },function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title : "Error",
            template : "Server Error!<br>Restart Application!"
        });
    });
})
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added these lines to AndroidManifest.xml 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: if your issue is not solved, add cordova plugin list to confirm that you properly added the geolocation plugin

Comment: I just tested it in a cell phone and works great, but doesn't render in my emulator. 
these are my plugins list:
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1-dev "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.2 "InAppBrowser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the emulator doesn't have a GPS and can not do realtime updates like you see in devices with GPS.

There are certain ways to test the behavior of the app's geospatial functionalities in an emulator. You have to do some work for it though.

Here are some references:

For [Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console) connect emulator through Telnet. (Useful [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator?answertab=votes#tab-top))