# Give fake location to Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location, genymotion

Is there a way to give my Genymotion android emulator a fake location, like USA for example, so I can test mobile ads and some other stuff?

Comment: Genymotion have this option to emulate fake locations.

Comment: where is it? ........

Answer (score 19):

You can change the GPS location and can set Latitude and Longitude according to your need, check below Screen Shots:

On the right hand side corner in you Genymotion Emulator you can see the GPS option,
[image]

When you click this option you will get one dialog as below:
[image]

Here you can change Latitude and Longitude.
Hope it help..

Comment: just did it, but ads still show for my local area, and not USA. I even went in Settings>Location>Mode> and there selected GPS only

Comment: Try to find out Location programmatically  and than set Ad like this:  AdRequest.Builder.setLocation(Location)

Comment: yes, this way it seems to be ok, but isn't the point of this GPS setting of Genymotion to set an actual location, so you won't need additional coding?

Comment: This answer very much helpful to me.Thank you

Comment: I want to enable it, however, the GPS button is disabled ! What's going on ?

Answer (score 3):

When using Genymotion free (personal) edition, you lost the position you gave when closing the genymotion.

To provide programming comfort to yourself, an app might be use that provide a fake location for android. There are a lot of apps at [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=fake%20gps%20location&c=apps&hl=tr).

I use [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=tr).