# Google Maps - LastLocation Object returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, genymotion

I am using `Genymotion` as my emulator and this is what I did to set my `google maps` project up:

1. Successfully downloaded `googleplay services` unto the emulator.
2. Enabled `Locations` in the emulator's settings
3. Signed into google in order to get `google location history`
4. Allow `google` to get the location history of the emulator

I also added all the permissions in my `manifest file`; here is the code for my Activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

LatLng latLng;
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mFragment;
Marker mCurrLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    } else {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position
            mGoogleMap.clear();
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocation = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "LastLocation is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

After running this multiple times, the Location Object (mLastLocation) always returns null. Any ideas why this is happening? does `google` not know the location of the emulator via my internet provider or some sort?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709329/give-fake-location-to-genymotion-emulator

Comment: Thanks Suresh! the post you linked solved my problem :)