# ngCordova geolocation plugin doesn't working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I make an hybrid app with ionic.I want to use ngCordova to get my location.The app works fine in browser but when i emulate in android virtual device doesn't working.I've installed all that say in ngCordova docs.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the emulator via Telnet and push the gps location.

Connect via telnet :

```
telnet localhost <console-port>
```

and then fix push a geo location with this command line

```
geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>
```

a better way is to use a real android device and add it to your adb with the following command line

```
adb devices
```

However you can get the log of your device by executing this command line

```
 adb logcat
```

Ref:

[How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#ops-location

Hpe this help

Regards