# Google API not getting Geo-Locatiion

Tags: android, gps

I was told to follow the tutorial at https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

When I did, I wasn't getting a Geo-Location, out of frustration I downloaded the premade program and that isn't working too. It's telling me "No location detected. Make sure location is enabled on the device." Which is only said when the location is null.

```
  /**
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

/**
 * Location sample.
 *
 * Demonstrates use of the Location API to retrieve the last known location for a device.
 * This sample uses Google Play services (GoogleApiClient) but does not need to authenticate a user.
 * See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/tree/master/QuickStart if you are
 * also using APIs that need authentication.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    protected String mLatitudeLabel;
    protected String mLongitudeLabel;
    protected TextView mLatitudeText;
    protected TextView mLongitudeText;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
        mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,
                    mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel,
                    mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

I honestly, do not know why it refuses to give me a GPS update, would someone be able to help me? I checked the emulated phones setting and it does allow applications to use GPS data. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Geo location might not be provided could not be got using a emulator, just try using a phone,or else find below link to get geo location in an emulator.[How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LocationManager` instead for fetching locations at regular intervals and distance

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000; // one second
    int distance = 0; // 0 means ignore triggering based on distance
   try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, interval, distance, this);
    } catch (SecurityException ignored) {}
```

And your `Activity` class must extend `LocationListener` which implements below methods

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       double latitude = location.getLatitude();
       double longitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

Comment: I wish I could use that but I need to follow the tutorial, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the main issue was that since this only calls the GPS location once, and onstart, that means there can be a chance no GPS data exists, this is remedied by making it so it continually asks for an update if the GPS data = null. The tutorial never explains that, and im posting it just in case someone else has issues.