# Why does my Android Emulator not getting location data from my MacBook Pro?

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I have an Android Emulator that uses the latest emulator version (26.1.4-4266726). My Macbook runs Sierra 10.12.6. My application runs perfectly smooth on the emulator the only thing is, it is not getting my macbook's location. I tried opening the emulator's maps application and it show the Googleplex as the current location. Is there anyway I can properly emulate that the application is using location services?

The location settings is turned on on both the Android Emulator and Macbook Pro. The location settings for the emulator is set to High Accuracy as well

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36980274/5308778) hope this one help you.

Comment: It is actually very easy. You open emulator control and before you start application you click Send location with lat and long and then you will have location. The fact that emulator has internet connection because your Macbook has it does not mean that it also has location