# How to simulate multiple latln position on a device (not emulator)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gps

I want to simulate a driving car on a road on an Android device (like on an emulator).

On an emulator, I am loading a kml file, and the emulator reads it and set the next position each second. So I looked if I could do the same programmatically, but what I found doesn't look very good.

I found a `KmlLayer` and it said that I have to create a layer of the map where all the position will be placed as a `marker`. And after that I would be able to get those marker positions. The problem is that I only want to get positions from the kml file and set those positions one by one each second to simulate the car moving. And creating a layer of the map, placing all the marker and get the position of each marker isn't  a too heavy way do what I want?

Is there any other way to simulate a car moving on a road with specific `LatLn` on an Android device?

Comment: Install this in your device : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps

Comment: The architecture of your application should provide ways for receiving data from different sources: from GPS, from file, from database etc. Something  like [Repository](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator