# Get GPS location in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I wanted to get the manually set GPS latitude and longitude for my emulator in the main activity because `getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` is returning null location. As seen in many posts here, I tried adding the LocationListener and call

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this)
```

But my code is never going inside the onLocationChanged function and hence my app is unable to get the location which I manually entered. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing here?

How can I fetch the manually entered latitude and longitude in my emulator settings?

Comment: Check this answer. It might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098850/7789575

Comment: I have done this. But I am unable to get the value I entered in my MainActivity

Comment: add more details to your question.What do you want to do exactly. If possible please update your code.

Comment: you can try passing location via emulator settings , Under location tab,  While app is running update location callback method should receive the same LatLng values you passed there.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you. It was a minor error from my side in the emulator settings. It worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score -1):

The android emulator named `'multi-memu'`,you can set your GPS position in just a few clicks.