# Problem with navigator.geolocation failing in cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I'm working on my first cordova project and I'm testing on an emulator.

I need to use navigator.geolocation to get the coordinates.

I have installed the cordova geolocation plugin and it's also mentioned in the config.xml file.
I've given location access to the app in the emulator settings and I also click the "send" button in the the emulator's extended settings.

Despite this, the geolocation keeps failing and I don't know why.

Here is the js code:

//Initialise entry page for the first time and handle entry page input validation

```
$(document).delegate("#entry_page","pageinit",function()
{

  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout: 30000});
  }

  //rest of code

    if(latitude == null || longitude == null)
    {
      alert("Location not given. Please allow location access and refresh the application");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(dateTime == null)
    {
      alert("Date & Time not acquired");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    // remaining code
    });
  });


  //Get location and time values on successful location access
  function onSuccess(position)
  {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    today = new Date();
    date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();
    time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    dateTime = date+' '+time;

  }

  //Throw error if location access is not possible
  function onError(error) {
    var txt;
    switch(error.code)
    {
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      txt = 'Location permission denied';
      break;
      case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      txt = 'Location position unavailable';
      break;
      case error.TIMEOUT:
      txt = 'Location position lookup timed out';
      break;
      default:
      txt = 'Unknown position.'
    }
    alert(txt)
  }

  //Reinitialise entry_page when it is revisted again
  $(document).on("pageshow", "#entry_page", function()
  {

    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout: 30000});
    }

    changeHeaderName("#chickenNameHeader");
    clearFields();

});
```

P.S. I'm using Nginx and Nodejs. My Nginx is configured for https.

Comment: what does your `error` say?

Comment: It asks for permission and then fails immediately saying 'location unavailable' before I can even click allow

Comment: you mean the error object says 'location unavailable'  ?

Comment: Yes. That error is put in an alert message

Comment: are you trying on a device?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph no, on the emulator.

Comment: i am not sure how it would fetch location for android, I know ios stimulator does it. Can you try on an actual device with GPS turned on please?

Comment: I managed getting the location from the emulator in another android app but that wasn't cordova based.

I'll try testing it on my phone later as i'm in the university right now.

Comment: [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) to get locations in android. But I am sure this should work on an actual device

Comment: I have already done the answer described by eden in that post. Doesn't work for my cordova project only

Comment: maybe try installing the geolocation plugin?  you may be missing the permission in the manifest file

Comment: Done and done. I gave permissions, i mentioned it in the config.xml file and I installed the plugin.

I think it may have something to do with my server. Since geolocation only works in https context, i dont know if my node server is allowing it

Answer (score 1):

If your android version is >= Android M, you need to ask user for the run-time location permission first.

Use [this cordova plugin](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions) to request the location permission.

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

permissions.hasPermission(permissions.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, function(status){

   if (!status.hasPermission) {

    //Does not have the required permission, request for the same
    permissions.requestPermission(permissions.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
       function(status) {
         if(status.hasPermission) {
            //Has permission already, fetch the location
         }
       }, function () {

   });

  }
  else {
    //Has permission already, fetch the location
  }
});
```

Comment: I will try this out and let you know if it works. By M, I assume you mean Marshmallow?

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva yes Marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

Worked fine for me with this code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
  // Show a map centered at latitude / longitude.
  alert(latitude + '==' + longitude);
});
```

I'm using Object destructuring (ES6).