# How to get the Get Current Latitude, Longitude and Address for my app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my coding below, it is giving me an output but its not my exact location. (Its giving me some location in USA).
I implemented a facility to get the user's current location using the Fused Location Provider API. and also i created intent service to fetch address from latitude and longitude using Geocoder.
Please help me out with this issue for my project. 
Here is my coding below:

This is my main Activity

```
public class ContactDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;


    public TextView  LatLong;
    ProgressBar pb;

    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_details);
        resultReceiver=new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

        LatLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlong);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

 findViewById(R.id.buttonGetCurrentLocation).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            ContactDetails.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION
                    );
                } else {
                    getCurrentLocation();
                }
            }
        });


 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION && grantResults.length > 0) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getCurrentLocation();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {

        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //  return;
        }
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ContactDetails.this)
                .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ContactDetails.this)
                                .removeLocationUpdates(this);
                        if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0) {
                            int latestLocationIndex = locationResult.getLocations().size() - 1;
                            double latitude =
                                    locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLatitude();
                            double longitude =
                                    locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLongitude();
                            LatLong.setText(String.format("Latitude: %s\nLongtitude: %s", latitude, longitude));
                            Location location= new Location("providerNA");
                            location.setLatitude(latitude);
                            location.setLongitude(longitude);
                            fetchAddressFromLatLong(location);

                        } else {
                            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }, Looper.getMainLooper());


    }
    private void fetchAddressFromLatLong(Location location){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, location);
        startService(intent);
    }
    private class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
         AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            if(resultCode== Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
                add.setText(resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY));
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ContactDetails.this, resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

FetchAddressIntentService.java

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        super("FetchAddressIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if(intent != null) {
            String errorMessage="";
            resultReceiver=intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
            Location location= intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);
            if(location==null){
                return;
            }
            Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses=null;
            try {
                addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                errorMessage= exception.getMessage();
            }
            if (addresses== null || addresses.isEmpty()){
                deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT,errorMessage);
            }else {
                Address address=addresses.get(0);
                ArrayList<String> addressFragments= new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
                }
                deliverResultToReceiver(
                        Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                        TextUtils.join(
                                Objects.requireNonNull(System.getProperty("line.separator")),
                                addressFragments
                        )
                );
            }
        }
    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String addressMessage) {
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, addressMessage);
        resultReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    }
}
```

Constant.java file

```
class Constants {
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME="com.example.registration";
    static final String RESULT_DATA_KEY= PACKAGE_NAME + ".RESULT_DATA_KEY";
    static final String RECEIVER= PACKAGE_NAME+ ".RECEIVER";
    static final String LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA = PACKAGE_NAME+ ".LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA";
    static final int SUCCESS_RESULT=1;
    static final int FAILURE_RESULT= 0;


}
```

[Screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoTj8.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your app on the simulator, then you should send a location to simulate it. The default is the location of GooglePlex, which is the one you are receiving.

Otherwise maybe your precission is not correct.

try to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) for simulating locations.

Hope it helps.