# navigator geolocation is not picking current location

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, geolocation, expo

I'm trying to use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to find lat long using android emulator.
It is not picking any location. I thought that problem is with my emulator. I tried using Telnet, and also altered my code based on:

```
{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 1000, maximumAge: 1000 }
```

I also tried `false` option. Nothing worked. Please note that in expo snack i can get location using "Web" option, but not as android and IOS. so the problem is not browser based

I just found the code on expo snack, it is not showing the lat long here as well. Please see if you can help me find what is the problem. I prefer not to use Geolocation of expo, and would like to stick to the `navigator.geolocation` option.

Please see snack link below:
https://snack.expo.io/@coder79/geolocation-example

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set up the geolocation in the Android Emulator. You can find a very good guide on how to set it in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098850/8798164

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, so I think the problem is that if you request for geolocation and then get denied, you can never request for geolocation again and nothing will happen. Maybe you would have to go to site settings for your own page to allow geolocation.

Comment: thanks Timothy, or is it my desktop? becuae my code also has same issue. But what can be done?

Comment: What type of computer are you using? I know that some browsers don't support it. You can find a complete list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It is Dell. The location option is ON. Also please see snapshot of chrome. Please note that in expo snack i can get location using "Web" option, but not as android and IOS. so the problem is not browser based

Answer (score 1):

You should set the geolocation permissions for iOS and Android (like [this guide](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-use-the-geolocation-api-in-a-react-native-app-b5e611b00a0c) shows under the section *Setting Permissions for iOS and Android*)

Even if you use the navigation api, your app still need to work with these permissions.

But remember, **[navigator.geolocation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/geolocation) is deprecated** in React-Native. You should not rely on this api, even while using the expo-cli.

I would recommend the [Location](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/) api if you are using the expo-cli.

For someone using a bare RN project, you could use [@react-native-community/geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation) instead.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am following what help seys, but i still got these two errors, when i run  this  :Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

2.
@ react-native-community/geologation: NativeMOdile.RNCGeolocation is null. To fix this issue try:

Run react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation

Comment: I am new and i got it wrong, I am using expo-cli, i think i can use navigator.geolocation

Comment: [navigator.geolocation](https://archive.reactnative.dev/docs/0.58/geolocation#docsNav) is deprecated since RN 0.58. This would be a bad practice to use this api since it's no longer maintained. Using the expo-cli, i would recommend you to use the expo [Location](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/) api.