# Is there any solution for getting location in android emulator flutter

Tags: android, flutter, location, emulation

I'm using geolocator package for the purpose of device current location when I'm using my app in my real device that's perfectly run and returning back the exact long and lang when I'm using the same app in android emulator nothing is returning how I can resolve this issue?[image: image is given below in which i'm using lacation's class object]

Comment: Here is a similar issue in the location package repo: https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/532

Answer (score 1):

The default location in Android Emulator is *Googleplex, Mountain View (US)*. You cannot track Emulator location but can simulate it. An example how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098850/14231239)

Comment: I've follow all the steps that are mentioned in the given link but still can't access my emulator's location that I've entered manual and  gpx/kml both.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me, was changing the location and then going into Google Maps on the emulator, enable location there and wait for it to jump from the Googleplex location, to the custom location. Then I restarted my app, and it returned the correct location.