# Geolocator showing lat and long of google building in USA

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
    var position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
    );
    setState(() {
      currentposition = position;
      print(currentposition);
      locationdata();
    }),}
```

I wanted to find and use my location using geolocator. So as to check if my location is right, I used  print. Surprisingly, the lat and long that I get are not from my place. They are of google building in USA. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try running app in real device

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use Real/Physical device for that.** It will pick default location of USA as you are running it in emulator.

You can emulate the location see here: [How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)