# Android gets the wrong location of the emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I made an app that stores the position of the device (latitude and longitude) and to actually test it I tried to change the GPS location of the emulator from the default location in Mountain View to a random location in Rome. [I followed this thread to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator). The problem is that my app still stores the default location rather than the new location I set.

This is how I access the location:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 m 
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        Location location = null;

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                throw new Exception("GPS must be turned on!");
            }
            else {
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        throw new Exception("Permission needed for location!");
                    }

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                }

                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS turned off");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Turn on the GPS!");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Impostazioni", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I use those methods and actually store the location on the Database:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;

    String ServerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/api/insert.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        final Button bottone1 = findViewById(R.id.bottone1);

        bottone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(HomeActivity.this);
                Location location = gpsTracker.getLocation();

                if (location != null) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    Date datenotformatted = new Date(location.getTime());
                    String date = format.format(datenotformatted);

                    String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
                    String lon = String.valueOf(longitude);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    insertData(lat, lon, date);
                }
                else {
                    gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void insertData(final String latitude, final String longitude, final String date){

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String first = latitude;
                String second = longitude;
                String third = date;

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitudine", first));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitudine", second));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", third));

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    if (httpEntity == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Errore.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "Success.";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(latitude, longitude, date);
    }
```

The location the app gets everytime:
[image: The location the app gets everytime]
[image: A]

The actual location of the emulator I set:
[image]

Comment: Did you set the location? I believe the location resets on every relaunch of the emulator

Comment: Adding a location does not set it on the emulator. You need to select the location from the list and set it

Comment: @AhmadSattout Yeah I did that by setting it through the button under the location list.