# Emulator location issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working in a project in Android Studio and I need to get my current location .

I searched and I see that there is a way to set location in Extended Controls but I need to get my real position ( I'm trying with Google Map in emulator and it's giving me a location in San José ) is there anyway to get the current location by using an Emulator in android studio ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: what's the difference or why is it relevant to get your actual location ? why isn't an emulated/fake location sufficient ?

Comment: if you want to find your current location use a physical phone

Comment: I need to do a tracking app so everytime it need to get my real/current location

Comment: @ACTPOHOM there is no way to get the current location with an emulator ?

Answer (score 4):

If you open the extended controls (3 dots) on your emulator and select the location tab you should be able to change the location to a route (1st picture) or a point (2nd picture) make sure to press "Set Location"

[image: google maps and the emulator controls for gps]

[image: single point controls]

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I did that but I need the real/current location I know it's working when I use a physical device but I need to have my real location in an Emulator

Comment: If it needs to follow a set route my suggestion would be to record a gpx/kml with your physical device and import that to the emulator

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.tracklia&gl=US

Comment: Thanks you for your help , is there any other possibility to have location without any use a physical device ( I don't have an Android device ) ?

Comment: Have a look at this question and see if you can get any ideas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: I saw it before posting my question it doesn't help me a lot , they are setting manually latitude and logitude

Comment: I think the point of the emulator is that every thing is 100% customizable, the best i can suggest is to open google maps in your browser and get your exact location coordinates and paste them into the emulator gps settings

Comment: An emulator will never be as good as testing on a physical device