# Emulated coordinates not working Android Studio 2021.2.1

Tags: android-emulator, gps

In my app I get wrong coordinates when running on Emulator.
To set coordinates I opened extended controls, found a location with the search bar and set it (also saved the point ) as suggested here
[How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)
but then when app starts still gets the wrong coordinates

```
GeolocatorUniversal.getLocation() location is Latitude: 37.4218708, Longitude: -122.0841223, which seems to be the default test location...
```

Where do I have to set it then if not here?

Many thanks

[image]