# how to get my current location in google maps api?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, geolocation

I'm working on my study android project where I need to place 5 random markers within a 10km radius of my geolocation. Here's my function to generate random coordinates:

```
     fun generateRandomCoordinates(min: Int, max: Int): LatLng {
        val coordinates: LatLng
        val currentLong: Double
        val currentLat: Double
        val meterCord = 0.00900900900901 / 1000
        //Generate random Meters between the maximum and minimum Meters
        val r = Random()
        val randomMeters: Int = r.nextInt(max + min)
        //then Generating Random numbers for different Methods
        val randomPM: Int = r.nextInt(6)

        //Then we convert the distance in meters to coordinates by Multiplying number of meters with 1 Meter Coordinate
        val metersCordN = meterCord * randomMeters.toDouble()
        val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
        currentLong = locationResult.result.longitude
        currentLat= locationResult.result.latitude
        coordinates = when (randomPM) {
            0 -> LatLng(currentLat + metersCordN, currentLong + metersCordN)
            1 -> LatLng(currentLat - metersCordN, currentLong - metersCordN)
            2 -> LatLng(currentLat + metersCordN, currentLong - metersCordN)
            3 -> LatLng(currentLat - metersCordN, currentLong + metersCordN)
            4 -> LatLng(currentLat, currentLong - metersCordN)
            else -> LatLng(currentLat - metersCordN, currentLong)
        }
        return coordinates
    }
```

that code results with **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete** at line         **currentLong = locationResult.result.longitude**

I tried to use addOnCompleteListener but somehow it didn't worked out. So I tried to add Thread.sleep(50) and that works but I think that it's not how sane person should code. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as It can take some time to update the position, you should register a callback for retrieving the current location. Note that this code only returns the last known location, if you want to get updated location continuously, you can use the *requestLocationUpdates* method.

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                // Logic to handle location object
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on your location. 2. check whether location is null or not:

   ```
   fun generateRandomCoordinates(min: Int, max: Int): LatLng {
    val coordinates: LatLng
    val currentLong: Double
    val currentLat: Double
    val meterCord = 0.00900900900901 / 1000
    //Generate random Meters between the maximum and minimum Meters
    val r = Random()
    val randomMeters: Int = r.nextInt(max + min)
    //then Generating Random numbers for different Methods
    val randomPM: Int = r.nextInt(6)

    //Then we convert the distance in meters to coordinates by Multiplying 
        number of meters with 1 Meter Coordinate
    val metersCordN = meterCord * randomMeters.toDouble()
    val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation

    if (location != null) { //<------ 
    currentLong = locationResult.result.longitude
    currentLat= locationResult.result.latitude
    coordinates = when (randomPM) {
        0 -> LatLng(currentLat + metersCordN, currentLong + metersCordN)
        1 -> LatLng(currentLat - metersCordN, currentLong - metersCordN)
        2 -> LatLng(currentLat + metersCordN, currentLong - metersCordN)
        3 -> LatLng(currentLat - metersCordN, currentLong + metersCordN)
        4 -> LatLng(currentLat, currentLong - metersCordN)
        else -> LatLng(currentLat - metersCordN, currentLong)
      }
      return coordinates
    } else { //<------
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Null location!",
                                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   ```

   }

If the above code returned `else` part, then most likely your last location is empty (if you are using emulator!) In emulator like BlueStacks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd> (for other emulators see this post: [How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279647/6576302)) and set a location, then try your code again.